# todonotes text overlap and vertical spacing problem

Tags: marginpar, marginnote, todonotes

I am trying to use both margin and face some problems.

1. I cannot start the paragraph with marginpar, i will have to add imaginary space \hspace{0pt}. Otherwise, it will align with previous paragraph. Is there other method to solve this problem?
2. I have defined `\lnote` and `\rnote` with `\reversemarginpar` and `\normalmarginpar` respectively to switch both side of margin. However, they need to be separated by empty line otherwise the `lnote` will take `\normalmarginpar` instead. And due to the blank line, `rnote` is not aligned with the paragraph. Any idea to fix this?
3. Switching the `\reversemarginpar` and `\normalmarginpar` make the todonotes overlap each other. There are no option in todonotes that allow v-offset. Do you have any idea how to solve this?[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[backgroundcolor=white]{todonotes}

\newcommand{\lnote}[1]{\hspace{0pt}\reversemarginpar\marginpar{\raggedleft #1}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\rnote}[2][noline]{\normalmarginpar\todo[#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}
\lnote{\textbf{Photosynthesis}} Photosynthesis is a process used by plants and other organisms to convert light energy into chemical energy. 

\rnote{For more information, see \href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthesis}{\textcolor{blue}{here}}}

\lnote{\textbf{Glycolysis}} Glycolysis is the metabolic pathway that converts glucose into energy.

\rnote{For more information, see \href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycolysis}{\textcolor{blue}{here}}}

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With a customized `description` environment you can achieve the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[backgroundcolor=white]{todonotes}

\newcommand{\lnote}[1]{\hspace{0pt}\reversemarginpar\marginpar{\raggedleft #1}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\rnote}[2][noline]{\normalmarginpar\todo[#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[itemindent=0mm, labelsep=3mm, align=right,parsep=\baselineskip]
    \item[Photosynthesis]\rnote{For more information, see \href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthesis}{\textcolor{blue}{here}}} Photosynthesis is a process used by plants and other organisms to convert light energy into chemical energy.
    \item[Glycolysis]\rnote{For more information, see \href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycolysis}{\textcolor{blue}{here}}} Glycolysis is the metabolic pathway that converts glucose into energy. 
\end{description}

\end{document}
```